# Read Named Pipe with _lread

Tags: c++, named-pipes, mql4

I have a code which use **`kernel32 _lread()`** function to read some files, which it works well with.
Now I wanna know if I can read a named pipe with **`_lread()`** in `WINAPI`?

```
 int hFile = _lopen(U2A(file_path), 0);
   if (hFile < 0) Comment("Please Connect Writer");

   if (hFile > 0) 
   {
     uchar chBuff[1024];
     int res = _lread(hFile, chBuff, 1);

     res = _lread(hFile, chBuff, 350);
     ls_308 = CharArrayToString(chBuff, 0, res, CP_UTF8);
  // Alert(Ls_84);
     ls_308=StringSubstr(ls_308,0,StringFind(ls_308,"\r\n",0));   

     if (_lclose(hFile)<0) Print("Error closing");
```

Can I read named Pipes( **`\\\\.\\pipe\\Name`** ) using **`_lread()`** `WINAPI` function?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Make sure the server has an open pipe .

Comment: Why do you use `_lread`?

Comment: @MicroVirus, the code is a bit old code reading csv from a writer, so i just don't wanna touch anything living in the code, either by replacing it with Readfile or some other type, so the reason i wanna use the _lread